# Project stopped working after installing android preview L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've installed Android preview L, after that my project stopped working.
Error message: **"Failed to parse : must be an integer number or codename."**

My project gradle settings:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Comment: I've posted manifest file

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion "L"
buildToolsVersion "L"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion "L"
    targetSdkVersion "L"
}
}
```

Comment: but I need support android 2.3

Comment: You can add "android-support-v4" library for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```